# Plotting Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z}$ in rectangular coordinates

Tags: plotting

I'm trying to plot the Riemann surface of $\sqrt{z}$ with this command:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{t,u,Re[Sqrt[t + I u]]}, {t,-1,1}, {u,-1,1}];
```

but the output isn't anything like what I get in polar coordinates. What am I missing?

Comment: `Sqrt` will only give you one branch of the complex square root.

Comment: Combining two plots `ParametricPlot3D[{{t, u, Re[Sqrt[t + I u]]}, {t, u, -Re[Sqrt[t + I u]]}}, {t, -1, 1}, {u, -1, 1}]`?

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean something like this?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{r Cos[θ], r Sin[θ], Re[Sqrt[r E^(I θ)]]}, {r, 0, 1}, {θ, 0, 2π}]
```

[image]

Comment: You're right; in the end what I was really missing is that in rectangular coordinates the plot is clipped in a rectangular shape (as projected on the XY plane), while in polar coordinates it has an evident circular simmetry. The resulting image is quite different.
Now how do I accept the answer if I asked the question as a guest?
Thank you,
Enrico